# AWS Cloudwatch scheduling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I currently have a lambda function which stops my EC2 instances (4 virtual servers) and have created a schedule using Cloudwatch to kick off this lambda function to stop my servers at 6:30PM Mon-Fri. That part works beautifully.

However, if I run an application specific analysis batch on my servers at, for example, 3PM, some times the application running the analysis takes 4-5 hours to complete, which means that CloudWatch would essentially stop the servers at 6:30PM in the middle of the analysis process. Is there a way to build in an exception to check if CPU utilization on the servers is greater than 10%, to delay the cloudwatch event?

I tried creating an alarm event in CloudWatch to shutdown the specific EC2 servers if CPU utilization metric is <10% but that would essentially turn them off during the work day if not being utilized, and that is not what I need.

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to write a script (lambda function) that would check to see if CPU utilization at 6:30PM Mon to Fri is below 10%, if it is, then stop the servers. If not, then keep checking every hour. At this point, I'd love any and all suggestions please. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can define this with [AWS Step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/)
You could create a worflow that:

- Runs every hour (see [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-target.html)
- Every hour check time of day and CPU load on server (with [2 lambda function Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html))
- If the time is between 630pm and midnight, from Mon to Fri, check CPU - [see resultpath doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html))
- If CPU is <10% shutdown the instances. Otherwise do nothing